# Rigging shft+ctrl+v does not flip animation properly

Tags: animation, rigging

[image]

This is the 0 and the 60th frame this pose.

If I copied everything (press a and ctrl+c) and then when I went to frame 30 and pressed shift+ctrl+v, then I get this.

[image]

Do you notice how the arm is not the same as the other arm on frame 0, why is this?

Comment: maybe you need to rotate some of your bone correctly in Edit mode, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5806 Here is the link to my file, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said it's a bone axis problem, so follow these steps to fix it:

[image]

Comment: It seems to work better, but it still is not working right, I deleted the 30th frame, I copied the 0th frame and then moved to 30th frame, shift+ctrl+v and the hand is slight not matching the right hand. Any idea?

Comment: oh yes sorry, also rotate right forearm + hand -90°

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I wanted to understand everything that is going on, what is the x axis mirror and why does it have to be disabled? Why do I have to rotate those 3 bones, what was causing those bones to not flip properly?

Comment: x axis mirror will mirror all the change you make on a side in edit mode to the other side, so if you rotate a bone in one side and don't want it to happen the other side, you need to disable it / you need to have the same bone orientation on both side, otherwise it won't be mirrored correctly when you'll animate